# could not resolve archetype org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quicstart:1.1 from any of the configured repositeries

Tags: java, maven

while creating maven project i am getting this Error which is there in image

[image]

Comment: i removed .m2 folder antd trying to create ,but not getting cretaed

Comment: try from command line. are you connected to internet ? are you behind any proxy ?

Answer (score 0):

Most probable reason: Your proxy/firewall blocks access to MavenCentral.

Other possible reasons:

- Your `settings.xml` in `.m2` contains wrong mirrors.
- The content of `.m2/repository` is broken. Remove this directory, it will be recreated automatically.
- Eclipse needs to be restarted.